# How to replace special characters within a text with a space in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Problem Statement:** *If a special character is found with alphabets, then replace it with one space. And, if it is found with digits, then simply ignore.*

Actual Scenario:

1. `$45`
2. `4.5 inches`
3. `Task.This is good.`
4. `Hello, How $are you. This is good.`

Expected Scenario:

1. `$45`
2. `4.5 inches`
3. `Task This is good`
4. `Hello  How  are you  This is good`

I have tried writing [one regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%20%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B%5E%20a-zA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%7C%20%5Cd%2B%5B%5E%20%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%7C%20%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B%5E%20%5D%5Cd%2B%7C%20%5B%5E%20a-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%7C%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B%5E%200-9a-zA-Z%5D)&test_string=2.2%202.2%20ddddd.dfhghg%20222.d%20d.2222%203%3B3%20d%2B3%200.33%20mm%20dddd.334easdf%2045.23%20d.dga.45%205.632asdf%20.%3B097%20asdf.343%2022.%20211%20sfasd%2056565%20343.343%2F98%26*%2056%2577%20dd%5Edk%203..2%20d..asdf.34%20d...3%20f%26d%20t%26t%204*D%20mm%20nn%2044%2055%20gh%2067%20hjk%20777%2089%20%26%20*%20()%20%5E%26*(%20%20%20%3B8%2089%3B%20hi.%20hello%3B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) to find out the texts which follows this pattern, but not sure exactly how to replace special characters in that text with a space.

[image]

**For e.g.** In above image, expected output would be `'ddddd dfhghg'`, `'222 d'` etc.

Can this scenario be handled by re.sub(pattern, replacement, input)? If yes, please tell how :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a character set with wrapped with negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\d)([.,$])(?!\d)
```

Put all the chars that should be replaced inside the brackets: `[.,$]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nu0Imz/1/)

Explanation:

- `(?<!\d)`negative lookbehind - ensure that there is no digit just before a matched character
- `(?!\d)`negative lookahead - ensure that there is no digit just after a matched character
- `[...]` character set with all the special chars you want to replace

Comment: Bingo!! This is exactly which I was looking for. Thanks a ton @mrzasa

Comment: One more question: What exactly I want is to consider all special characters except space in capturing group and am doing this way     

pat = re.compile(r"(?<!\d)([!\"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?!\d)")      

print(pat.sub(" \\1 ", text))     
Can this pattern (pat) be optimized further?

Comment: I think it's OK

Answer (score 3):

I would try something along these lines, which is most certaintly suboptimal in performance but functional

```
class Replacer
    def __init__(self, special_chars):
        self.special_chars = special_chars

    def replace(self, s):
        for ch in self.special_chars:
            for match in re.finditer(ch, s):
                if not is_followed_by_numbers(s, match.start())
                    s = replace_at_index(s, match.start())

    def is_followed_by_numbers(self, s, start):
        pass # Provide your implementation

    def replace_at_index(self, s, index):
        pass # Provide your implementation
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge for answering the question. Answer provided mrzasa is more crisp and clear and hence I have accepted that answer. Thanks again for providing a solution to my problem :)